# Optimum Regular Expression: Repeat Occurrences

Tags: php, regex

I try to replace the following tag and its content with empty string:

```
<a href="http://localhost/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png" class="wall-image-anchor" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png" /></a>
```

Note that the href url inside `<a>` tag can be anything. So is the content inside `<a>`, in this case `<img>` with its content.

So far I got the following code:

```
$text = preg_replace('@(.*?)<(?:a\b.*?class="wall-image-anchor".*?)>.*?</a>(.*?)@si', '$1$2', $text);
```

This code should transform the following string:

```
zzzzz<a href="http://localhost/zz/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png " class="wall-image-anchor" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/zz/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png" alt="Image/photo" /></a>ffff<br /><a href="http://localhost/ada/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png " class="wall-image-anchor" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/ada/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png" alt="Image/photo" /></a>ffffgg ffff<br /><a href="http://localhost/dad/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png " class="wall-image-anchor" target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/dad/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png" alt="Image/photo" /></a>ffffgg'
```

into:

```
zzzzzffff
ffffgg ffff
ffffgg
```

This code works. My question is: is there any other way to make it faster?

regards

Comment: Maybe `echo strip_tags(str_replace('</', "\n</", $string));`? Use `nl2br` after the `strip_tags` if this is for a browser. Alternatively you could use a parser. As for speed you'll have to run tests. or perhaps I misread that and you want to keep the `<br>`s (your `into` example doesn't have those). `echo strip_tags($string, '<br>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is correctness.  As written, your regex will match starting at the beginning of the first `<a>` tag, no matter what its `class` attribute is. ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS0hE1/1))  You need to replace the internal `.*?`s with something that can't match beyond the tag boundaries, i.e., `[>]*`.

That will also cut down enormously on the amount of backtracking, improving performance considerably.  The other thing you should do is get rid of the `(.*?)` at either end.  Anything not matched by the regex is unaffected by the replace operation, so you're just making it do unnecessary work.

Here's how it should look:

```
'@<a\b[^>]*class="wall-image-anchor"[^>]*>.*?</a>@si'
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS0hE1/2)

Answer (score 0):

You know how lazy match works, so how come you didn't just do this?

```
$var = "zzzzz<a href=\"http://localhost/zz/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png \" class=\"wall-image-anchor\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://localhost/zz/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png\" alt=\"Image/photo\" /></a>ffff<br /><a href=\"http://localhost/ada/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png \" class=\"wall-image-anchor\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://localhost/ada/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png\" alt=\"Image/photo\" /></a>ffffgg ffff<br /><a href=\"http://localhost/dad/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png \" class=\"wall-image-anchor\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://localhost/dad/photo/448e7d40ed468d73c5f9caba573f6273-0.png\" alt=\"Image/photo\" /></a>ffffgg'";

$output = preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $var);
```

Or are you only trying to specifically match a href and img?

PS. Please space out your string next time so it's easier to see what parts you're trying to catch.

Comment: yes, I need to detect specific class. This is answered by Alan